# Argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to import a csv file into R, and I was able to do this by

```
Lab2x<-read.table("Lab2x.csv").
```

From here I'm trying to calculate the average, standard deviation, standard error, t-statistic and the p-value.  I was taught to do this using:

```
xbar <- mean(Lab2x)               # calculate the sample average
sd <- sqrt(var(Lab2x))            # calculate the sample sd
se <- sd/sqrt(12)                 # calculate se of sample average
tstat <- (xbar - 2.27)/se         # calculate the t statistic
pvalue <- 2*(1-pt(abs(tstat),11)) # calculate the p-value
```

However, when I try to use any of these I get the error:

Warning message:
In mean.default(Lab2x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

What am I doing wrong/missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lab2x is a list with one or more columns, so the functions expecting a numeric vector will report that they are getting the wrong type of argument. Try substituting `Lab2x[[1]]` for Lab2x, assuming it is the first column you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to tell without seeing your data (try `head(Lab2x)`).

My advice is to check the data types of `Lab2x`:  `read.table` constructs a `data.frame` from the data, and your values are currently being interpreted as `character` vectors rather than `numeric` values at the moment. A few problems it could be:

- A few columns aren't numeric, and the warnings are being thrown there
- All columns aren't numeric, which means its struggling to find the numbers:

  - Is it reading in the correct number of columns? try `read.csv` instead.

Comment: My data for Lab2x is
     V1
1)  2.899964
2)  1.102373
3  2.067420
4)  1.918675
5)  2.403308
6)  2.465267
7)  1.537496
8)  2.309874
9)  1.648227
10) 1.676975
11) 2.221423
12) 2.237677

I'm able to open the file on R, I just can't seem to do anything with the data, like finding the average.